# How to sort a list of zip objects by specified criteria?

Tags: python

I wrote an Airbnb scraper that goes through every subpage of home listings for a specified location and for every subpage it returns zip object like this:

```
subpage = zip(names, prices)
```

After scraping single subpage, I add the `subpage` zip object to a list:

```
all_subpages.append(subpage)
```

So in the end `all_subpages` is a list of zip objects, each one containg data from one subpage.

My problem is I want to display data from `all_subpages` in HTML table form and I want this data sorted by price.

So my question is: how do I print the contents of `all_subpages` ordered by price?

Expected output:

```
    Name                 Price
    Apartment 3          10 GBP
    Apartment 1          15 GBP
    Apartment 2          20 GBP

    etc.
```

Comment: What is `zipped`?

Comment: Sorry, I meant `zip`, corrected now.

Comment: You should add an example of what `subpage` looks like. Is this HTML? floats?

Comment: @dawg, `subpage` is two string lists zipped together.

Comment: It sounds like you don't actually want to be storing your data by subpage, and should instead store individual `name, price` pairs. Try replacing `all_subpages.append(subpage)` with `all_subpages.extend(subpage)` (though you might want to rename the list, since the subpages are no longer relevant).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My take on the problem:

```
from itertools import chain

names = ['78', '1', '3']
prices = ['15', '20', '10']

names2 = ['82', '11', '33']
prices2 = ['1', '2', '100']

all_subpages = []

subpage = zip(names, prices)
all_subpages.append(subpage)

subpage2 = zip(names2, prices2)
all_subpages.append(subpage2)

print('Home number\tprice')
for (name, price) in sorted(chain.from_iterable(all_subpages), key=lambda v: int(v[1])):
    print(f'{name}\t\t{price} GBP')
```

Output:

```
 Home number    price
82      1 GBP
11      2 GBP
3       10 GBP
78      15 GBP
1       20 GBP
33      100 GBP
```

Answer (score 1):

Given:

```
l1=["Apartment 1", "Apartment 3","Apartment 2"]
l2=['15 GBP','10 GBP','20 GBP']
```

You can sort on the second element lexicographically like so:

```
>>> sorted(zip(l1,l2), key=lambda t: t[1])
[('Apartment 3', '10 GBP'), ('Apartment 1', '15 GBP'), ('Apartment 2', '20 GBP')]
```

If you want the same thing numerically, you can do something like:

```
>>> sorted(zip(l1,l2), key=lambda t: float(t[1].split()[0]))
```